# Want to show UIActivityIndicator on UITableViewCell while setting images on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a table with horizontal and vertical scrolling in UITableView,and each cell has a UIImageView and i am  setting image on cell's UIImageView by URL.I want to show the ActivityIndicator on all cells until the images is downloaded.I have search a lot but didn't find anything good.
Here is my code for CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    __block ArticleCell_iPhone *cell = (ArticleCell_iPhone *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //added for uiacticvaty indicator on uitableviewcell

    UIActivityIndicatorView *loadingActivity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                                initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [loadingActivity startAnimating];

    loadingActivity.frame = cell.thumbnail.frame;
    loadingActivity.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90  , 90);

    [loadingActivity setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    UIView* parent = [cell.thumbnail superview];
    [parent addSubview:loadingActivity];
    [parent bringSubviewToFront:loadingActivity];
//
    //added for uiacticvaty indicator
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell=[[[ArticleCell_iPhone alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kCellWidth_iPad, kCellHeight_iPad) withNSDict:dict] autorelease];
        __block NSDictionary *currentArticle = [self.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

        dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[currentArticle objectForKey:@"thumbnail_url"]]]];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [cell.thumbnail setImage:image];
//                [loadingActivity stopAnimating];

                cell.titleLabel.text = [currentArticle objectForKey:@"Title"];


            });
        }); 

    }



//    [cell.imagefooter setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider leveraging open source solutions like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) (with [UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage)).

Answer (score 0):

It´s necessary to have a "background" to the cell.imageView... But must be a image, not just a frame. So just create a UIImage as a "white background" and set in cell.imageView.image. The code will be:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
UIImage *whiteback = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"whiteback.png"];
 cell.imageView.image = whiteback;
[cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
cell.textLabel.text=@"Carregando...";
[whiteback release];
[spinner release];
```

The whiteback.png is just a 25x25 pixels white square...
Thanks

Comment: The image view is still a view so you should be able to set the `backgroundColor` rather than an image.

Comment: the text comes when i scroll ……and it doesn't get remove when image is downloaded.

Comment: remove that cell.textLabel.text=@"Carregando...";

Answer (score 0):

Give tag to your activity indicator using custom cell.

```
  UITableViewCell *aCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *aActivity=(UIActivityIndicatorView *)[aCell viewWithTag:1];
    [aActivity startAnimating];
    return aCell;
```

I tried this code in my demo and its working perfectly.